# keeping record of students and quiz in database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make web based quiz system.

I have a table of `students` which have the record of all the students

A table of courses which keeps the record of all the `courses`.

And each student can have upto 4 courses which record is kept in a seprate table.

Each course can have more than one `quiz` and students enrolled in that specific course have to attempt that particular quiz.

Now I want to ask how i can keep the record of those students in my database who have attempted the quiz specific to their coruse. I am unable to conceive the structure of table or logic how I can do this please any body help me.

Comment: We're here to help with specific problems. Teaching you how to design a relational database is WAY too broad and WAY offtopic.

Answer (score 2):

prepare your database something like below.

```
Students
-----------
id | name | ..............
```

-

```
Courses
-------------
```

### id | course_name | ...........

```
Student_courses
------------------
```

### id | student_id | course_id | .........

```
Quizes
------------
```

### id | course_id | ........

```
Student_quizes
--------------
id | student_id | quiz_id | ..
```

To know about students who have attempted a quiz applicable for a particular course, you can get it from `student_quizes`. You have to make an `inner join` of `student_quizes` to `courses` table to know the course to which the quiz is applicable.